# Sort complex string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input string like, `CF10, CF6_S01, CF11_S01`. I want to sort this in ascending order like, `CF6, CF10, CF11`. Not concern about `_S01` in string. I am trying to split based on first number after alphabets but didn't work.

```js
    var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    var reN = /[^0-9]/g;

    return function(a, b) {
        var aA = a[key].replace(reA, "");
        var bA = b[key].replace(reA, "");
        if (aA === bA) {
            var aN = parseInt(a[key].replace(reN, ""), 10);
            var bN = parseInt(b[key].replace(reN, ""), 10);
            return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
        }
    };
```

Can someone help me how I can produce output: `CF6, CF10, CF11` using regular expression in javascript?

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: The code you just inserted has nothing to do with what you're asking

Comment: @Adelin it does, it's the sort function.

Comment: @EECOLOR hopefully :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could separate the first part into not number characters and the number. Then sort by first part and second.

```js
function getParts(s) {
    return s.match(/^(\D+)(\d+)/).slice(1);
}

var array = ['CF10', 'CF6_S01', 'CF11_S01'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = getParts(a),
        bb = getParts(b);
        
    return aa[0].localeCompare(bb[0]) || aa[1] - bb[1];
});

console.log(array);
```

For soting just by the first number, you could omit other characters.

```js
function getValue(s) {
    return s.match(/\d+/); // returns an array with only one element
}

var array = ['CF10', 'CF6_S01', 'CF11_S01'];

array.sort((a, b) => getValue(a) - getValue(b));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this simple one-liner solution:

```js
var arr = ['CF10', 'CF6_S01', 'CF11_S01']

console.log(arr.sort((a,b) => (a.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.match(/\d+/)[0])))

// if you don't want _S01 part
console.log(arr.sort((a,b) => (a.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.match(/\d+/)[0])).map(e => e.split('_')[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple version specific for your use case without the use of a regular expression:

```
'CF10, CF6_S01, CF11_S01'
  .split(',')
  .map(x => x.trim())
  .sort((a, b) => {
    const [aa] = a.split('_')
    const [bb] = b.split('_')
    return aa.slice(2) - bb.slice(2)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution using `regex`

```js
let arr = ['CF10', 'CF6_S01', 'CF11_S01'];

arr.sort((a,b) => {
  let var1 = a.split('_')[0].split('CF')[1];
  let var2 = b.split('_')[0].split('CF')[1];
  
  return var1 - var2
})

console.log(arr)
```

You can simply use `split` function to extract the numeric part and perform sorting based on it